# How to check which repository a specific folder corresponds to

Tags: git

I have a couple very similar looking folders on my machine that correspond to different repositories stored on github.

How can I check the git address that a specific folder corresponds to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
git remote show origin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `git remote -v` inside the folder in order to list the remotes registered with the local repository. The 'origin' remote is the one set up by 'git clone', so that's the one you' re looking for.